# Recording RTSP stream

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp

I want to record video data coming from Camera(through RTSP H.264). Can anybody help me how to record rtsp stream using gstreamer?(Please provide gstreamer command line details). Recording will be in MPEG4 formate

Regards
Kiran

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will stream the video and output to your screen.

`gst-launch rtspsrc location=rtsp://some.server/url ! decodebin ! xvimagesink`
`gst-launch uridecodebin uri=rtsp://some.server/url ! xvimagesink`

To record the stream to your drive using MPEG4:

`gst-launch rtspsrc location=rtsp://some.server/url ! decodebin ! mpegtsmux ! filesink location=file`

[rtspsrc](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-rtspsrc.html) from the reference manual and [another useful resource](http://blog.elphel.com/2009/11/interfacing-elphel-cameras-with-gstreamer-opencv-opengl-and-python-get-profit-of-dsp-or-gpu-based-optimisation-control-camera-settings-from-python-application-or-human-interface-device-hid/).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried those 2 commands. First Command I am able to see rtsp stream. But second command which should record data but its not happening. I have done little bit modification after study the doc from link which you provided. gst-launch-0.10  -e rtspsrc location="rtsp://10.17.8.136/mediainput/h264" latency=100 ! rtph264depay byte-stream=false ! capsfilter caps="video/x-h264,width=640,height=480,framerate=(fraction)25/1" ! mp4mux ! filesink location=video.mp4. Its is recording data is H264 formate. Can you guide me how to do recording in MPEG4.

Comment: Check out the [available plugins](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugins.html) and see which one works for your to do the encoding.